# How can I update "no results" text in Search as a content manager?

Tags: search

I want to customize the "no results" search page, but I do not have access to any of the server files. I only have general "administrator" access. Thanks.

Comment: are you able to install module ? if so might be [string override](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module may help you

Comment: I am unable to install anything.